# Why does the Entity Framework generate nested SQL queries?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Why does the Entity Framework generate nested SQL queries?

I have this code

```
    var db = new Context();
    var result = db.Network.Where(x => x.ServerID == serverId)
        .OrderBy(x=> x.StartTime)
        .Take(limit);
```

Which generates this! (Note the double select statement)

```
SELECT
`Project1`.`Id`, 
`Project1`.`ServerID`, 
`Project1`.`EventId`, 
`Project1`.`StartTime`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`ServerID`, 
`Extent1`.`EventId`, 
`Extent1`.`StartTime`
FROM `Networkes` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`ServerID` = @p__linq__0) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`StartTime` DESC LIMIT 5
```

What should I change so that it results in one select statement? I'm using MySQL and Entity Framework with Code First.

## Update

I have the same result regardless of the type of the parameter passed to the `OrderBy()` method.

## Update 2: Timed

```
Total Time (hh:mm:ss.ms)    05:34:13.000
Average Time (hh:mm:ss.ms)  25:42.000
Max Time (hh:mm:ss.ms)  51:54.000
Count   13
First Seen  Nov 6, 12 19:48:19
Last Seen   Nov 6, 12 20:40:22
```

Raw query:

```
SELECT `Project?`.`Id`, `Project?`.`ServerID`, `Project?`.`EventId`, `Project?`.`StartTime` FROM (SELECT `Extent?`.`Id`, `Extent?`.`ServerID`, `Extent?`.`EventId`, `Extent?`.`StartTime`, FROM `Network` AS `Extent?` WHERE `Extent?`.`ServerID` = ?) AS `Project?` ORDER BY `Project?`.`Starttime` DESC LIMIT ?
```

I used a program to take snapshots from the current process in MySQL.

Other queries were executed at the same time, but when I change it to just one SELECT statement, it NEVER goes over one second. Maybe I have something else that's going on; I'm asking 'cause I'm not so into DBs...

## Update 3: The explain statement

The Entity Framework generated

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', '<derived2>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '46', 'Using filesort'
'2', 'DERIVED', 'Extent?', 'ref', 'serveridneventid,serverid', 'serveridneventid', '109', '', '45', 'Using where'
```

One liner

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'network', 'ref', 'serveridneventid,serverid', 'serveridneventid', '109', 'const', '45', 'Using where; Using filesort'
```

This is from my QA environment, so the timing I pasted above is not related to the rowcount explain statements. I think that there are about 500,000 records that match one server ID.

## Solution

I switched from MySQL to SQL Server. I don't want to end up completely rewriting the application layer.

Comment: First of all LINQ To SQL and Entity Framework are different things. Second why do you think this query is bad? Did you do performance analysis or at least run explain?

Comment: Yes I build them manually in pure SQL. With 28 million records there is milliseconds vs minutes

Comment: Sorry for the typo with Linq To SQL

Comment: @SimonEdström - There is nothing wrong with that query, and in fact is what it SHOULD be doing.  You would not want to order your 28 million records, but rather you want to select the subset constrained by the where clause, then order the subset and apply the limit.  This results in a smaller working set for the order by.  If you are seeing a huge problem with this, then there is likely some other problem here.  How many records are returned from the Where clause?

Comment: Sorry for be missleading about how it's execute in the MySQL server. Maybe there something else going on here. But if I take the raw query and execute it it will go faster with my setup if I just have one SELECT statement.

Comment: @SimonEdström - Can you post your queries with their average execution times over 3-5 attempts?

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the query plan differs here

Comment: @Bobson I added some timeing..

Comment: @Stilgar I added the execution plan. Or at least I think it's the same as running the explain statement in MySQL. Am I totally wrong and something else magic is happening somewhere?

Comment: Now we wait for someone who understand databases better than us to explain what the explain statements really mean and why MySQL generated them that way. It seems to me that the first query sorts first and then filters but why is that...

Comment: The poor performance with the nested select is probably a MySql specific problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201049/mysql-with-entity-framework-is-slow-because-of-derived-tables-how-can-i-fix-it (also read the comments below the question)

Comment: @Slauma - Oooh, interesting find.

Comment: @MystereMan See the update and Slaumas comment

Comment: @SimonEdström - Why are you using MySQL anyways?  Is your database running on Linux?  Is it running on the same machine as the server?  Of so, a better choice could be Sql Server 2012 LocalDb (which is no cost).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the easiest way to build the query logically from the expression tree.  Usually the performance will not be an issue.  If you are having performance issues you can try something like this to get the entities back:

```
var results = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Network>(
    "SELECT Id, ServerID, EventId, StartTime FROM Network WHERE ServerID = @ID", 
    serverId);

results = results.OrderBy(x=> x.StartTime).Take(limit);
```

Comment: I bet this wouldn't happen in SQL Server ;)  I wonder how their execution plan building routines differ.  I'm off to try and reproduce.

Comment: I am curious about this too but too lazy to do the research myself :)

Comment: This is not a valid solution if you want to maintain the order by and take operation inside SQL to reduce result returned by the query

Answer (score 3):

My initial impression was that doing it this way would actually be more efficient, although in testing against a MSSQL server, I got <1 second responses regardless.

With a single select statement, it sorts all the records (`Order By`), and then filters them to the set you want to see (`Where`), and then takes the top 5 (`Limit 5` or, for me, `Top 5`).  On a large table, the sort takes a significant portion of the time.  With a nested statement, it first filters the records down to a subset, and only then does the expensive sort operation on it.

***Edit:** I did test this, but I realized I had an error in my test which invalidated it.  Test results removed.*

Comment: Side thought:  I really wish the person who asked for all searches to be logged actually *looked* at that data.  Right now, all it's good for is detecting hacking scripts and spambots, because they search for nonsensical queries.

Comment: There is no where clause at all in your first query. I'm not a MySQL expert but I would expect any decent database engine to produce a query plan which executed the where clause first in either case.

Comment: @JamesGaunt - Oops, you're right.  I had a copy & paste error when I was testing.  Proof invalidated.

Comment: @Bobson You should update your answer and tell people that you tested with MS SQL server. It's confusing!

Comment: @SimonEdström - Good point.  I had that in there when I had my test results, but I edited it out.

Answer (score 3):

Why does Entity Framework produce a nested query?  The simple answer is because Entity Framework breaks your query expression down into an expression tree and then uses that expression tree to build your query.  A tree naturally generates nested query expressions (i.e. a child node generates a query and a parent node generates a query on that query).

Why doesn't Entity Framework simplify the query down and write it as you would?  The simple answer is because there is a limited amount of work that can go into the query generation engine, and while it's better now than it was in earlier versions it's not perfect and probably never will be.

All that said there should be no significant speed difference between the query you would write by hand and the query EF generated in this case.  The database is clever enough to generate an execution plan that applies the WHERE clause first in either case.

Comment: Have a look at the execution plan. It's a huge performance differance between the different statement.

Comment: I don't see that.  Both query plans implement the WHERE at the first opportunity. If you're seeing very different timings it suggests something else is going on. Either that or this is a MySQL 'feature', but MySQL is a widely used and respected DB engine and I can't believe it makes such a fundamental error.  Are you calling both tests with identical parameters?

Comment: Ah! Just read comment from @Slauma in question! Wow. Stop using MySQL until they sort it out if that's the case. A sub-query is not a temp table!

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like an alternative

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the EF to generate the query without the subselect, use a constant within the query, not a variable.

I have previously created my own .Where and all other LINQ methods that first traverse the expression tree and convert all variables, method calls etc. into Expression.Constant. It was done just because of this issue in Entity Framework...

Comment: When EF needs to execute a query, it compiles the expression tree to a db command. This is very expensive for complex queries. If you change your variables to constants, EF will not be able to reuse the cached compiled stuff, and will need to recompile. For complex queries that is an extreme perfomance killer.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this post because I suffer from the same problem. I already spend days tracking this down and it it is just a poor query generation in mysql.

I already filed a bug at mysql.com http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75272

To summarize the problem:

This simple query

```
context.products
    .Include(x => x.category)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

gets translated into

```
SELECT
`Limit1`.`C1`, 
`Limit1`.`id`, 
`Limit1`.`name`, 
`Limit1`.`category_id`, 
`Limit1`.`id1`, 
`Limit1`.`name1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`name`, 
`Extent1`.`category_id`, 
`Extent2`.`id` AS `id1`, 
`Extent2`.`name` AS `name1`, 
1 AS `C1`
FROM `products` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`category_id` = `Extent2`.`id` LIMIT 10) AS `Limit1`
```

and performs pretty well. Anyway, the outer query is pretty much useless. Now If I add an OrderBy

```
context.products
    .Include(x => x.category)
    .OrderBy(x => x.id)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

the query changes to

```
SELECT
`Project1`.`C1`, 
`Project1`.`id`, 
`Project1`.`name`, 
`Project1`.`category_id`, 
`Project1`.`id1`, 
`Project1`.`name1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`name`, 
`Extent1`.`category_id`, 
`Extent2`.`id` AS `id1`, 
`Extent2`.`name` AS `name1`, 
1 AS `C1`
FROM `products` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `categories` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`category_id` = `Extent2`.`id`) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`id` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Which is bad because the `order by` is in the outer query. Theat means MySQL has to pull every record in order to perform an orderby which results in `using filesort`

I verified that SQL Server (Comapact at least) does not generate nested queries for the same code

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[category_id] AS [category_id], 
[Extent2].[id] AS [id1], 
[Extent2].[name] AS [name1], 
FROM  [products] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[category_id] = [Extent2].[id]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[id] ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually the queries generated by Entity Framework are few ugly, less than LINQ 2 SQL but still ugly.

However, very probably you database engine will make the desired execution plan, and the query will run smoothly.