# Horrifically inefficient query generated by Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Here's the query I want:

```
select top 10 *
from vw_BoosterTargetLog
where OrganizationId = 4125
order by Id desc
```

It executes subsecond.

Here's my Entity Framework (6.1.2) equivalent in C#:

```
return await db.vw_BoosterTargetLog
    .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .Take(numberToRun)
    .ToListNolockAsync();
```

And here's the SQL that it generates:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId], 
    [Project1].[BoosterTriggerId] AS [BoosterTriggerId], 
    [Project1].[IsAutomatic] AS [IsAutomatic], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[CustomerUserId] AS [CustomerUserId], 
    [Project1].[SourceUrl] AS [SourceUrl], 
    [Project1].[TargetUrl] AS [TargetUrl], 
    [Project1].[ShowedOn] AS [ShowedOn], 
    [Project1].[ClickedOn] AS [ClickedOn], 
    [Project1].[BoosterTargetId] AS [BoosterTargetId], 
    [Project1].[TriggerEventGroup] AS [TriggerEventGroup], 
    [Project1].[TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers] AS [TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers], 
    [Project1].[TargetTitle] AS [TargetTitle], 
    [Project1].[BoosterTargetVersionId] AS [BoosterTargetVersionId], 
    [Project1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Project1].[CookieId] AS [CookieId], 
    [Project1].[CoalescedId] AS [CoalescedId], 
    [Project1].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName], 
    [Project1].[ShowedOnDate] AS [ShowedOnDate], 
    [Project1].[SampleGroupSectionName] AS [SampleGroupSectionName], 
    [Project1].[Selector] AS [Selector], 
    [Project1].[SelectorStep] AS [SelectorStep]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId], 
        [Extent1].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName], 
        [Extent1].[BoosterTriggerId] AS [BoosterTriggerId], 
        [Extent1].[IsAutomatic] AS [IsAutomatic], 
        [Extent1].[SampleGroupSectionName] AS [SampleGroupSectionName], 
        [Extent1].[Selector] AS [Selector], 
        [Extent1].[SelectorStep] AS [SelectorStep], 
        [Extent1].[BoosterTargetId] AS [BoosterTargetId], 
        [Extent1].[CookieId] AS [CookieId], 
        [Extent1].[CustomerUserId] AS [CustomerUserId], 
        [Extent1].[CoalescedId] AS [CoalescedId], 
        [Extent1].[SourceUrl] AS [SourceUrl], 
        [Extent1].[TriggerEventGroup] AS [TriggerEventGroup], 
        [Extent1].[TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers] AS [TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers], 
        [Extent1].[TargetTitle] AS [TargetTitle], 
        [Extent1].[TargetUrl] AS [TargetUrl], 
        [Extent1].[ShowedOn] AS [ShowedOn], 
        [Extent1].[ShowedOnDate] AS [ShowedOnDate], 
        [Extent1].[ClickedOn] AS [ClickedOn], 
        [Extent1].[BoosterTargetVersionId] AS [BoosterTargetVersionId], 
        [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
         CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS int) AS [C1]
        FROM (SELECT 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[OrganizationName] AS [OrganizationName], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[BoosterTriggerId] AS [BoosterTriggerId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[IsAutomatic] AS [IsAutomatic], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[SampleGroupSectionName] AS [SampleGroupSectionName], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[Selector] AS [Selector], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[SelectorStep] AS [SelectorStep], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[BoosterTargetId] AS [BoosterTargetId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[CookieId] AS [CookieId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[CustomerUserId] AS [CustomerUserId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[CoalescedId] AS [CoalescedId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[SourceUrl] AS [SourceUrl], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[TriggerEventGroup] AS [TriggerEventGroup], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers] AS [TriggerIgnoreIdentifiedUsers], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[TargetTitle] AS [TargetTitle], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[TargetUrl] AS [TargetUrl], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[ShowedOn] AS [ShowedOn], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[ShowedOnDate] AS [ShowedOnDate], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[ClickedOn] AS [ClickedOn], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[BoosterTargetVersionId] AS [BoosterTargetVersionId], 
    [vw_BoosterTargetLog].[Version] AS [Version]
    FROM [dbo].[vw_BoosterTargetLog] AS [vw_BoosterTargetLog]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[OrganizationId] = 4125
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC
```

It's ugly as hell, of course, as all EF queries are: I'm not complaining about that. My gripe is that in my testing, best-case, it executes about 10x slower than the first, and worst-case, about 100x slower.

For a query this simple, that seems way beyond all reasonable expectation.

Obviously I can execute SQL directly, or execute a sproc, or something of that sort. And while I'm waiting for feedback, that's what I'll do. But does anyone have any other suggestions about how to speed this up? Is there any way to encourage EF to generate reasonable SQL in a situation like this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the column type of `vw_BoosterTargetLog.ID`?

Comment: I assume by your naming that vw means it's a view?  EF and Views do not get along... you will always have various problems when trying to use them.  EF doesn't know how to optimize for a view.  It doesn't know what the PK's are.  It doesn't know any metadata in the actual backing tables...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Entity Framework generate nested SQL queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257760/why-does-the-entity-framework-generate-nested-sql-queries)

Comment: FWIW, `vw_BoosterTargetLog.Id` is a straightforward `int`. As for being a duplicate, I suppose this is a duplicate of every question ever that asks, "Why the **** is the Entity Framework so ******* slow?" :-(.

Comment: The query EF generates is actually not that unreasonable (readability aside) and the optimizer should have produced a plan equivalent to that for the simple query you presented above. The reason I asked after the column type is because of the appearance of `CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS int)` in the query -- if the column is not of type `INT`, the conversion makes the resulting `ORDER BY` horrendously inefficient because SQL Server has to convert all the values first before being able to order them. If the underlying column is an `INT`, though, the optimizer should see through this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Ah! After your comment, I double-checked, and it turns out that I'd lied. It's actually a BIGINT. That could be the issue. So the question becomes how I get  EF to recognize it as a long/Int64, I presume.

Comment: There you go. While converting from an integer type to a *bigger* integer type is no problem (conversion will be done after ordering), going the other way around forces a conversion step before the ordering and hence a full table scan. Are you using model-first or code-first EF? For code-first, I think you're simply free to change the property type in the entity to what it should be. For model-first, you can fiddle around with the model, but I don't know how to make the changes "stick" when EF regenerates it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - You were right. I just made the change (I'm using DB-first, and just updated the model in the EF designer), and execution time dropped from ~30 seconds down to .34 seconds. Much better. Throw it into an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The queries EF produces, while terrible from a readability perspective, are usually still quite <s>good</s> reasonable -- and I say that as someone who does almost all data access through stored procedures with hand-written queries. But in order for it to work, the model EF has of the database needs to match the actual database, or else conversions will be introduced, and when that happens it's *very* easy to get horrible performance drops while all the data is converted and no indexes can be used.

If we eliminate some nesting, the EF query can be simplified to

```sql
SELECT TOP (10) *
FROM (
    SELECT *, CAST(Id AS INT) AS C1
    FROM vw_BoosterTargetLog
    WHERE OrganizationId = 4125
) _
ORDER BY C1 DESC
```

(This is not the actual result set because `Id` isn't part of the final result set in the real query, but pretend I wrote out all the columns just like EF did.)

If `vw_BoosterTargetLog.Id` is not actually an `INT`, this forces a conversion of all rows before the ordering takes place, which is much slower. The solution is to figure out the actual type of the column (in this case, `BIGINT`) and update your model accordingly.